# Kafka Connect with custom Kafka Producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to build a KafkaConnect source connector and was wondering if it is possible to inject/use a custom Kafka Producer in the process. As per the documentation, I couldn't get much. Any ideas would help!

Comment: Why do you need custom Producer? What properties do you want to override?

Comment: We're building a generic producer for the client to not know any details about the cluster. We would like to abstract that. Also, we want to implement quotas on topics by means of throttling the producer.

Comment: Client needs to know the cluster. Quotas are maintaned externally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `poll` method of a SourceTask ***is*** the producer. Return a `List<SourceRecord>`, and they get serialized into the configured topic via the `Converter` definitions.

If you really want an actual instance of a Producer object, then you shouldn't be using the Connect API

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured as well. Thanks!

Comment: Then again, there really is nothing stopping you from creating a `new KafkaProducer` in that method, but you would need to configure it separately from the main Connect configurations

Comment: Also, another question I have is, where can I provide the bootstrap servers and schema registry configuration to the kafka connector?
Meaning, can I have the class that extends AbstractConfig also take the kafka bootstrap servers' details and produce to that cluster?

Comment: If I do configure a separate KafkaProducer in the poll method, what happens to the records that we return from the poll method? Will they not be produced again to the same topic?

Comment: To clarify: You would not make the producer send to the same topic as Connect. Connect Bootstrap servers are in the `connect-distributed.properties` file. The Schema Regsistry is defined as `(key|value).converter.schema.registry.url`... If you've downloaded Confluent Platform, then you can find examples in the etc/schema-registry directory

Comment: Found it, thanks. It's a little confusing as to which configuration is for what purpose. 
Is the `connect-distributed.properties` file separate than the properties file we provide as part of our source connector?